# Hook and Disable global keyboard shortcuts code

Tags: keyboard, python, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts

Is it possible to disable global hotkeys like ctrl + c, ctrl + v, ctrl + q, ctrl + w, ctrl + x, ctrl + alt + t...
Im trying create kiosk aplication where i need hook and disable specific keyboard shortcuts.

For now im using python library pynput for hooking shortcuts but i cant find how to disable function of this hotkeys

If someone know about some way to disable this hotkey functions tell me please.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi,  ubuntu 20.04.1 :) @David